# Detect if Outlook is connected to Microsoft Exchange via company LAN or Wifi

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm running a routine in Outlook that will check the "Sent" folder and will look thru public folders to see if emails in "Sent" folder need to be moved to public folder.  That's working well.
The problem is that I want this routine to be executed only if Outlook is connected to exchange via the company LAN on Wifi.  Reason being that when employees are at home using Outlook, they sometimes don't want that routine to be executed.
So the question being how to detect that Outlook is connected thru company LAN or WIFI?
I've found a way to detect if I'm connected to my company network by using this sub and associated function.  For that I try to access a file on the company server.  This is not that elegant but it got me that far

```
Sub TestNetwork()
Dim connected As Boolean

connected = CheckForNetwork()

If connected = False Then
    MsgBox ("not connected")
Else
    MsgBox ("connected")
End If
End Sub

Function CheckForNetwork() As Boolean
On Error GoTo end
If Len(Dir("\\company_name\company_name\company_name-000\Employee\ _     
          Employee Name\*.*")) > 0 Then
    CheckForNetwork = True
End If

Exit Function
end:
End Function
```

This will tell me if I'm connected to our company server or not  but it won't tell me if it's connected via my home network, a public WiFi spot in an airport or anywhere else.
I need to find out if Outlook is connected via company network or any other connection.

I'll greatly appreciate any help on that matter

Comment: Quite obviously, *any* Road Warrior should have to use **VPN** to connect, first, *to* "your company LAN. It should not be possible to reach your Outlook server, by any means, *except* by first connecting through VPN ... *"No Exceptions!"*  This will then remove the necessity to check how the connection was made, because any possible means of connection would now be "trustworthy."

Comment: Your Company LAN should have an IP address scheme  Check this against the network interfaces and if you don't have an IP in that range then you are not on your LAN.

Comment: Hello Sorceri, would you be kind enough to point me in the direction on how to retrieve the IP adress from VBA in Outlook?  I appreciate greatly your help.  Regards,

Comment: These example code will help you come up wiht a solution, http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/network/home/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of Sorceri, I found an easy way to retrieve the actual IP adress of a computer.  With that I'll be able to detect if the IP adress belongs to my company LAN of if the computer is connected to the Internet via another connection.  Inspiration comes frome here:  http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2014/12/get-public-ip-local-ip-mac-address-vba.html?m=1  and the final code is as follows

With the following code I first detect if Outlook is online or offline and the I retrieve the IP adress with the GetMyPublicIP function

```
Sub enligne_horsligne()


'olCachedConnectedDrizzle   600     The account is using cached Exchange code such that headers are downloaded first, followed by the
                                'bodies and attachments of full items.

'olCachedConnectedFull      700     The account is using cached Exchange mode on a Local Area Network or a fast connection with the Exchange server.
                                'The user can also select this state manually, disabling auto-detect logic and always downloading full items
                                'regardless of connection speed.

'olCachedConnectedHeaders   500     The account is using cached Exchange mode on a dial-up or slow connection with the Exchange server, such
                                'that only headers are downloaded. Full item bodies and attachments remain on the server.
                                'The user can also select this state manually regardless of connection speed.

'olCachedDisconnected       400     The account is using cached Exchange mode with a disconnected connection to the Exchange server.
'olCachedOffline            200     The account is using cached Exchange mode and the user has selected Work Offline from the File menu.
'olDisconnected             300     The account has a disconnected connection to the Exchange server.
'olNoExchange               0       The account does not use an Exchange server.
'olOffline                  100     The account is not connected to an Exchange server and is in the classic offline mode.
                                'This also occurs when the user selects Work Offline from the File menu.
'olOnline                   800     The account is connected to an Exchange server and is in the classic online mode.


Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim adresse_IP As String

Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.folder


Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")



 If (myNamespace.ExchangeConnectionMode = 700 Or   myNamespace.ExchangeConnectionMode = 600 Or myNamespace.ExchangeConnectionMode   = 700) Then
    MsgBox ("Outlook is online")
    MsgBox (Environ("userdomain") & "\" & Environ("username"))
 Else
    MsgBox ("Outlook is offline")
    MsgBox (Environ("userdomain") & "\" & Environ("username"))
End If

adresse_IP = GetMyPublicIP()

MsgBox ("The IP adrress is  " & adresse_IP)

End Sub
```

The function GetMyPublicIP is

```
Function GetMyPublicIP() As String
'source:  http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2014/12/get-public-ip-local-ip-mac-address-vba.html?m=1
Dim HttpRequest As Object

On Error Resume Next
'Create the XMLHttpRequest object.
Set HttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

'Check if the object was created.
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'Return error message.
    GetMyPublicIP = "Could not create the XMLHttpRequest object!"
    'Release the object and exit.
    Set HttpRequest = Nothing
    Exit Function
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Create the request - no special parameters required.
HttpRequest.Open "GET", "http://myip.dnsomatic.com", False

'Send the request to the site.
HttpRequest.Send

'Return the result of the request (the IP string).
GetMyPublicIP = HttpRequest.ResponseText

End Function
```